# Как асинхронно получить список портов?

Tags: c#, uwp, serial

Пытаюсь получить список `COM`-портов в `UWP`. в переменную `dis` я записываю список портов, однако он сразу переходит на следующую строку, хотя там стоит `await`. Как сделать так, чтобы `await` правильно ждал возврат всех портов?

```
try {
 string devSel = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
 var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(devSel);

 for (int i = 0; i < dis.Count; i++) {
  lst.Add(dis[i]);
 }
 serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(lst[0].Id);
} catch (Exception ex) {

}
```

Comment: Чтобы ждал, его надо использовать. Только если сразу после запроса поставить какое то использование `serialPort`, то у вас фактически синхронный код.

Comment: Ну а как подождать то? Мне в принципе без разницы - синхронный код или асинхронный.

Comment: Не сталкивался с этим интерфейсом, но в апи есть `GetResults`, плюс типично `await` асинхронен до использования переменной, в которую он забит, т.е. до любой операции с вашей переменной `serialPort`.